# JMeter Web Driver - Handling Windows Pop-up

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Looking for approach and syntax to handle windows pop-up in JMeter Selenium Web Driver to perform following actions:
-> Navigate to the file location, -> select the file, -> Open

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us. After you make a good attempt at doing this yourself and if you still have problems, you can update your question with details of the specific problem and what you have tried to solve it, and include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we are able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) is a **browser** automation framework it doesn't work with underlying operating system elements.

1. If you need to upload the file just locate the relevant [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) and invoke [sendKeys() function](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) providing the full path to the file you want to upload
2. If you need to download the file - extract [href attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) value and perform download using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

If automating OS windows is your strict requirement you may consider using i.e. [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class functions

Comment: Right now, I am using Robot framework with Selenium Webdriver and able to Paste(** using KeyPress **) the file location in the operating system / windows screen and successfully completed the operation. The script executes as expected for up to 3 users / Single machine (with Time delay) and the problem occurs when I try to scale up the users and perform the paste operations concurrently. The script fails here ** when multiple windows screen pops-up,** the paste operation is not happening.